# F# interactive fails to load with "error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'System' in any of..."

Tags: f#, mono, fsi

I am running Fedora 16, which gives me mono 2.10.5, but no F#. I have previously used a locally compiled version of mono, but am now using the packaged version. I am using the latest version of F# from the github repository, installed to a local directory (I do not have root on this machine).

When I run fsharpi (or mono path/to/file/fsi.exe) I receive the following error:

```
mono /home/scratch/local2/lib/mono/4.0/fsi.exe 

Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build (private)
Copyright (c) 2002-2011 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> 

error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'System' in any of
 /usr/lib64/mono/4.0
 /home/scratch/.../<current directory>
 /home/scratch/local2/lib/mono/4.0/
```

Googling yields some similar results, but the missing file is always a `.dll`. System.dll is certainly in /usr/lib64/mono/4.0.

Comment: have you run the install script?

Comment: Mono 2.10.5 package release includes F# already. Why do you have to install another F# version?

Comment: @JohnPalmer, I have run './configure --prefix=/home/scratch/local2 && make && make install'. I'm not aware of another install script in the github source distribution.

Comment: @pad, I have installed the Fedora 16 mono package. I read on the mono website that 2.10 includes F#, but this does not seem to be the case for the Fedora package for some reason.

The command `find /usr/lib64 -iname "*fsharp*"` does not find anything useful, and mono is installed under /usr/lib64.

Comment: I'm running Fedora 17 and 2.10.8 Mono, and I still can't find F# there.

Comment: @robin - I am not sure if the makefile will have run it but there is an `install.sh` script that registers some DLL's into the GAC.  It is present in the github release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I reverted to a slightly older version of F# from github before a recent merge from codeplex and everything works correctly. I have filed this as an issue here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/16

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer so that it's helpful for future visitors.

Comment: I just have to wait two more hours! I haven't been on StackOverflow long.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help or not (I realize it's discussing Ubuntu) but for what it's worth:

http://marinosc.webfactional.com/f-on-ubuntu-linux-with-mono-and-monodevelop/

To summarize the article in question:

- Install mono
- Setup parallel mono environment
- Install F#
- Install monodevelop dependencies
- Install monodevelop
- Install F# bindings

EDIT: 
Prior link was dead.

*NB: This article is from 2011.  It's extremely likely that the situation has changed in 8 years.*

Comment: I have previously used a parallel mono installation, but I'm now using the built-in Fedora packages. I'd rather not have to maintain my own versions of all the mono packages and deal with occasional breakage. The problem that prompted me to switch to using the Fedora packages is that the latest monodevelop I compiled just crashes.

Comment: link only answer, and dead link

Comment: I will see if I can find an archived copy of that link

Comment: @Maslow thanks for the heads up; I've found a live link to the material and I added some detail to help explain what I thought was helpful.